# How to validate ng-blur using Bootstrap & angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here I am using ng-blur for checking if email exits or not.It is working as I expected but why it's not getting validated in ng-show.

```
 <form name="f1" novalidate ng-submit="Save(emp)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <b style="font-family: Arial; text-transform: capitalize; text-align:left ">Enter EmailId</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 left-addon">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Mail" ng-model="Eamil" ng-blur="ChkAvailableEmail()" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                <span class="Error" ng-show="(f1.Mail.$dirty ||submitted) && f1.Mail.$error.email">Please Enter Your Valied Email</span>
                <span class="Error" ng-show="f1.Mail.$error.ChkAvailableEmail">Email in Use Please try new one</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**AngularJs**

```
$scope.ChkAvailableEmail = function () {
    var chk = {
        Email: $scope.Eamil
    }
    var mail = $Myservice.GetValidEmail(chk);
    mail.then(function (d) {

    })
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public JsonResult ChkEmail(string Email)
{
var x = (from n in db.Accessors
         where n.Email == Email
         select n).FirstOrDefault();
return new JsonResult { Data = x, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

}
```

Comment: Create a fiddle or plunkr pls. Where is JS code?

Comment: ok im  editing with Js code

Comment: Can you create a plunkr, i can make out much sense from these snippets

Comment: sry i dont know how to create plunker if ur free i will assign my team viewr

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/oBQpUy7Rl4dNxX4bgZpM?p=preview

Comment: Have a look at it https://plnkr.co/edit/KUA7z9?p=preview